# intellilock customValue not workng

Tags: c#, intellilock

This question is addressed ONLY for users of Intellilock... I believe there aren't much, but who knows...

They have a field called "customValue", which, in case of "CustomEnabled" enables my SW to store a string into CustomValue, and use it as the license.

I have now a case where this value isn't getting updated.

Too bad intellilock protected SW isn't debuggable [license active only when SW protected], so all I have is a log line:

```
License.CustomValue=txt
if (License.CustomValue!=txt)
    Log("Custom value not updated!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out finally.
there really is a limit with the length of "Custom_Value".

In my case I failed saving a string having a length of 36131, where as at 34000 it still worked.

Great example for why to have GOOD documentation, because this limit isn't written anywhere, and I shouldn't have any way to understand that the underlying structure of "Custom_Value" is limited by length...